# Remove list in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that stores an instance of the list. I want to remove the object from the sublist with IdName == "149"

```
        List<Product> productList = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Model = "Phone",
                TypeProd = new CheckTypes() { ChTypes = new List<CHType> { new CHType() { Id =  8, IdName = "261"}, new CHType () {Id = 9 , IdName = "149" } } }

            },
            new Product()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Model = "Printer",
                TypeProd = new CheckTypes() { ChTypes = new List<CHType> { new CHType() { Id =  8, IdName = null}, new CHType () {Id = 8 , IdName = "261" } } }
            }
        };

        var pr = productList.Select(s => s.TypeProd).Where(w => w.ChTypes.Any(a => a.IdName != null && a.IdName.Contains("149"))).ToList();
        // I
        var pr0 = pr.Select(s => s.ChTypes).Where(w => w.Any(a => a.Id == 9)).ToList();
        // II
        var pr1 = pr.Select(s => s.ChTypes).Except(pr0);
        // III
        pr.Select(s=>s.ChTypes).ToList().RemoveAll(a => a.Any(item => item.IdName.Contains("149")));
        foreach (var item in pr)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in item.ChTypes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item2.IdName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("End");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

I get to delete the whole sequence, but how to delete one element from the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Remove()` to remove a given item, or use `RemoveAt()` to remove the item at a given location.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are complicating it more than it needs to be. You simply need to loop over all the `ChTypes` `List` and remove the unwanted `ChType`. It can be easily accomplished by the below code

```
foreach (var chType in productList.Select(prod => prod.TypeProd.ChTypes))
    chType.RemoveAll(c => c.IdName != null && c.IdName.Contains("149"));
```

All your `LINQ` lines for `pr`, `pr0`, `pr1` and `pr.Select().ToList().RemoveAll()` are all unnecessary. Also, in your current code you are picking up only `CHType` with `Id = 9`, not sure if that is by mistake or your code is correct but your question missed specifying it.

Since the OP insists on avoiding `foreach` below is a a **bad** `LINQ` way of doing it

```
productList.Select(prod => prod.TypeProd.ChTypes)
           .Select(chType => chType.RemoveAll(c => c.IdName != null && c.IdName.Contains("149")))
           .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you very much, but all interest is in linq. Using a cycle, this is easy to do

Comment: @Tibomso Can you explain why you need to use `LINQ` to remove elements from a nested list? `LINQ` is typically used to extract (think select in sql) information, and not to mutate them.